# How to search in visual studio for a particular database table

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have 6 .dtsx (design) files (job steps) in visual studio.

For the most part the job steps run .sql code and drop/create/copy tables.

How can I search for where a particular table is touched?

I tried control-F and I browsed the menu for search options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this from visual studio.

If you open `.dtsx` files with a text editor it contains xml data. So you can search these files for a specific datatable from a text editor (like notepad, notepad++).