# Find tables/stored procedures in a list of SSIS packages

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have set of complex packages (.dtsx) in a particular folder. There are few issues needs to be addressed. I have to search few tables and stored procedures.

For now I manually open the package and scroll all the tasks in control flow to know where the table is exactly located but this is very hard to do.

Is any way I can directly search/find the given table/sp in the list of packages.

```
For example,

List of packages in particular folder

p1.dtsx
p2.dtsx
p3.dtsx
p4.dtsx
p5.dtsx

Assume that the table named employee exist in p4.dtsx.

My input would be employee and the expected output would be p4.dtsx
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search in visual studio for a particular database table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177192/how-to-search-in-visual-studio-for-a-particular-database-table)

Answer (score 3):

You can use powershell to search for a string in a set of files:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp\* -include *.dtsx | select-string employee
```

Get-ChildItem fetches the files from whatever your target folder is.  This output is piped to Select-String which can give you the exact line that the string appears on.  Note that it's searching xml so the output is inevitably a bit verbose.
m

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mark's answer, I would emphasize that SSIS packages are just plain text files.   You can open them in Notepad.   So any method of searching text files for a string will do

Another particularly handy solution would be to open the code-views of the packages to be searched in Visual Studio, and then do a ctrl-f and choose the option to search "all open files".